# how to insert jsp from javacode into another jsp

Tags: java, jsp

i'm working on legacy code so please don't start "why are you doing it that way", I know it's terrible implementation so lets skip that.

In a high level I have a JSP

```
<html:form action="/myAction" method="POST" onsubmit="beforeSubmit()">
...
        <table class="dialog">
            <% render.myhtml(out); %>
        </table>
...
</html>
```

render.myhtml(out) is in the java code as follows (i tried with both jsp:include and @ include :

```
public void myhtml(Writer w) throws IOException {
....
        String include = "<jsp:include page=" +"\"" +myobject.getPage() +"\"" + " />";
      //String include = "<%@ include file=" +"\"" +myobject.getPage() +"\"" + " %>";
        println(w, include);
...
}
```

but when I open the page I cannot see the include.. the source code shows that it's printing the include tag but not evaluating it:

```
<table class="dialog">
    ...
    <jsp:include page="/path/test.jsp" />
</table>
```

So it seems to me that this insertion is happening AFTER the inclusions are evaluated.. so the question is.. what can I do to make this work? I've thought about reading the JSP as string and pass it but that's pretty heavy on memory so I want to avoid that.

Comment: *i'm working on legacy code so please don't start "why are you doing it that way", I know it's terrible implementation so lets skip that* glad to know you know this is wrong but you have to accept it.

Answer (score 6):

Use [RequestDispatcher.include()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) in `myhtml()`.

You will need to pass in `application` from your JSP, as a RequestDispatcher is accessed via [`ServletContext.getRequestDispatcher()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29)

Application is a JSP implicit object: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_implicit_objects.htm

**EDIT**

JSP:

```
<html:form action="/myAction" method="POST" onsubmit="beforeSubmit()">
...
        <table class="dialog">
            <% render.myhtml(application, request, response); %>
        </table>
...
</html>
```

Java:

```
public void myhtml(ServletContext sc, ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws IOException {
....
        RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher(myobject.getPage());
        rd.include(req, res);
...
}
```

I also like @Luiggi's answer, and you have a choice really depending on how you want to write your code.

Comment: Thanks Paul, but could you please be a bit more specific as to the use of RequestDispatcher.include() to render the include and how that's retrieved in the jsp?

Comment: Note that passing the request and response is sufficient, since the servlet context is accessible using `request.getServletContext()`

Comment: @JB - Yes, good point. I'll leave as-is to show 3 of the implicit vars available to a JSP, but you're quite right.

Answer (score 1):

The writer that is passed to your `render.myhtml()` method is the HTTP response's writer. Everything you write to this writer goes to the browser, as is.

JSP is a server-side technology. It's compiled and executed at server-side. The browser doesn't know anything about JSP includes. So writing JSP code to the HTTP response writer doesn't make sense.

To do what you want to do, see [Paul Grime's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15959387/571407).

Answer (score 0):

The explanation of the error is detailed in [JB Nizet answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15959400/1065197).

If you want to dynamically include a jsp using `<jsp:include>` you should just dynamically set the name of the page you want to include. Basic example:

```
<table class="dialog">
    <jsp:include page="<%= render.myhtml() %>" />
</table>
```

Having

```
public String myhtml() {
    return "/path/test.jsp";
}
```

Comment: Yes I was thinking that too but the problem is that render.myhtml() as the "..." indicate has way more stuff in it, fields and so on, it could also contain more than 1 include.

Comment: @user1994202 if that's the situation (not stated anywhere in your question) the use [PaulGrime's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15959387/1065197)